# Where should I put these custom-permissions in django?

Tags: django, permissions, location

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#custom-permissions) shows how to put your own permissions to YourModel.Meta-class.

I'd like to have some permissions that don't have anything to do with a certain model. They would just allow/restrict different users to access certain views/pages.

What is the preferred place to define these permission in?
Should I create a dummy model for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define this kind of permissions in the "user profile" model, if it available (see [store additional information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) about users).

If "user profile" is not an option for some reason, you can still store additional permissions in `User` model.See [Programmatically creating permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#programmatically-creating-permissions) in django docs, for info how to create Permissions when setting `permissions` model Meta attribute is not possible (ie. User model is defined in 3rd app lib).